# vim with csharp-ls - how to disable reference counts?

Tags: c#, language-server-protocol, coc.nvim

I am on Debian bookworm and using Vim 9.0 with Coc plugin setup with csharp-ls as the language server for C#. I cannot figure out how to disable the reference counts:

[image: Reference Counts]

I have tried adding:

```
"csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false
```

to my ~/.vim/coc-settings.json but it does not work.

**UPDATE**
It looks like setting:

```
"codeLense.enabled": false
```

works, but I am wondering if that turned off additional functionality. So I guess my question is, how do I disable just the reference counts in code lense?